# COUNT() aggregate function in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

What is meant by putting `*` in `COUNT()` aggregate function as in:

```
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Does it counts all values of all the columns and see if they are greater than 1, which will be of-course be greater than 1 and quite understood.

But what is the point here?

Comment: Take a look at this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) to understand how to work with COUNT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COUNT()` counts the number of rows. You can find the difference if you have `NULL` value.

```
SELECT (*)             -- will include null value
SELECT COUNT(colName)  -- will only count NON NULL
```

consider this,

```
colA, colB
1   , A
2   , B
3   , NULL
```

`SELECT COUNT(*)` => returns 3 
`SELECT COUNT(colB)` => returns 2

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ce31/3)

Answer (score 0):

`*` is simply a placeholder. If you put `Count(1)` it will act just the same. `COUNT()` is useful for counting distinct values: `Count(distinct col)`